# .Select().Where() Statement no ouput

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I need to Save a User and his rights, but only the user with the given username . i have tried this syntax:

```
public ActionResult Index(string benutzer)
{
    var benutzer_hat_Recht = db.Benutzer_hat_Recht
           .Where(b => b.Benutzer_Name == benutzer)
           .Include(b => b.Benutzer)
           .Include(b => b.Rechte);

    return View(benutzer_hat_Recht.ToList());
}
```

But i don't get the right response in my view. Can someone tell me if there's something wrong with my syntax?

(the string passed to this action is benutzer = username, the model is `benutzer_hat_Recht = user_has_right`)

Comment: please post your view as well as what youre expecting `benutzer_hat_Recht` to contain as well as what it currently contains. Note you should probably be using `db.Benutzer_hat_Recht.Single` unless  multiple users can have the same username

Comment: Make sure the name is the same including lowercase and upper case and make sure you do not have a blanks at end.  Using Trim() will remove the blanks.  Normally I temporarily remove the where to verify the names are in the database.

Comment: If you expect only one user, rather use SingleOrDefault, instead of Where. You avoid the trouble of checking list for 0-length or length of 2 etc.

Comment: When you say "no ouput" (your spelling) do you mean that benutzer_hat_Recht is a List< Benutzer_hat_Recht > that contains 0 elements?

Comment: your code look's fine, one point i have not understood why you used `Inculde`, also it could be helpful if you add your input parameters (benutzer, dbo.Benutzer_hat_Recht)

Comment: Is b.Benutzer_Name a string? The it should be b.Benutzer_Name.Equals(benutzer);